# Cascade Multiple windows using Jquery Window plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using Jquery Window plugin v5.03 for my web application. I have to open the multiple windows on screen. But when I call the function to create a window they all open up in the center of the screen and overlap on one another such that previously opened screens are not visible.

I want the windows to open in such a way that at least the title bar and the cross icon is visible on top of the previously opened window. So that the user can know that another window is opened and previous windows are cascaded at the back and are slightly visible.

Please help.